# Is this a literal interpretation of "without reason"?

Tags: meaning

There was this quote in a movie:

> Men who kill without reason cannot be reasoned with.

There are many interpretations of "without reason"

1. It could mean that the person is mentally affected and cannot reason logically at all. "Without reason" is taken to mean "without any reason at all". His brain is faulty and causes him to kill.
2. He has reason to kill, but in his/her anger, the speaker say he has no reason. Suppose the speaker and the person being referred to are kings and bitter enemies at war. Both have valid reason to kill, but you still say "without reason".
3. He has no proper logical reason, but he/she is not mad. Maybe he/she is a slightly insane terrorist who believes in a reason that is logically invalid.

**Interpretation 1 is literal. Interpretation 2 is non-literal and contextual. Is Interpretation 3 literal?**

P.S.

I'm rather new to this site. I have nothing to do with English, I'm just curious.

Comment: There's another interpretation you're missing: that he killed without having a reason to kill.

Comment: @PeterShor is right. This is a play on the different meanings of *reason*. Such strategies are often evident in aphorisms.

Comment: @Robusto Yes. I'm just asking is interpretation 2 one of the **literal** interpretations.

Comment: I disagree with your initial premise. "Men who kill without reason..." is not the same as "Men without reason  who kill..." The first is adverbial, the second is adjectival.

Comment: The sentence is, perhaps intentionally, ambiguous.  The most "reasonable" single interpretation, however, would be that the man is not employing his logical facilities but is instead operating on prejudice and emotion.  The implication is that he is *capable* of employing reason but chooses not to.  (Note that I have not seen this movie.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference is simply to the fact that people sometimes do things without having any reason to. At one extreme, there may be two routes to your house that are exactly the same length; you have no reason to choose either over the other, but it is still necessary to walk home, so you choose one. At the other, [I shot a man in Reno just to watch him die](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/johnnycash/folsomprisonblues.html): in neither case is is possible to reason with the actor.

All three of your 'interpretations' are in fact possible explanations for the action, and as such have no place in a question about the phrase (besides other problems, such as the fact that no-one is both not mad and slightly insane).

Comment: I know interpretation 2 isn't the right one, but is it a literal one?

Comment: If it is not an interpretation, it is neither a literal one nor a figurative one.

Answer (score 0):

What Stoic the Vast meant was that people who lack morals/compassion can't be dissuaded, there is nothing emotional in that person to appeal to.

Comment: Perhaps you mean *dissuaded*? And even if you do, I think you're missing the point of the question.

Comment: Thanks for that, my computer didn't catch my error. As for the OP, it would be option 4: He has no logical reason and is a sociopath. 1 is out because Drago clearly demonstrates logic and reasoning in his campaign of conquest. 2 is out because when he slaughtered the chieftain council he was unprovoked (this is the example Stoic provided). And #3 is out because it is internally contradictory, being insane without being insane. 3, while a literal interpretation, is gibberish. Men who kill without reason (the normal or healthy condition of the mental abilities) cannot be reasoned with,